# Do you put "The" for "UK"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I am writing this sentence:

> I can put you in touch with a business owner in the UK

I'm not sure if I should put "the" for UK or not

Could you help please

Comment: We have a state in India called [Punjab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjab,_India). It is also addressed with a preceding '**the**'. There was a post regarding the same in [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, because it is **the** United Kindgom, not a random kingdom in the world.

The same goes for **The** United States, and not just "United States".

> **The** United States
>
> **The** United Kingdom
>
> **The** Democratic Republic of the Congo

But, you would of course say:

> England
>
> France
>
> Italia

More read and examples: http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/article4c.html

Comment: I'm not sure that this qualifies as an answer.